# Batch File ": unexpected at this time"

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line, scripting, batch-processing

The following lines of code are part of a larger script. Though this is the specific section creating issues when running. After the initial prompt and user input the script faults out providing the error `: unexpected at this time`. After looking at my code and some online documentation it looks as if everything I did should be correct. Though I am sure I am missing something minor that is causing this to happen.

```
::Changes Date/Time
echo The current date and time is %date% %time%
SET /P TIMECHANGE=Would you like to change the time (y:Yes):

if /i "%TIMECHANGE%" == "y" (
    SET /P POSTIME=Please enter new time (HH:MM:SS):
    time "%POSTIME%"
)

SET /P DATECHANGE=Would you like to change the date (y:Yes):

if /i "%DATECHANGE%" == "y" (
    SET /P POSDATE=Please enter new date (MM-DD-YYYY):
    date "%POSDATE%"
)

tzutil /s "Eastern Standard Time"
```

Edit:
Through some more poking around I found that the issue is occuring on the line:

```
if /i "%TIMECHANGE%" == "y" (
```

Comment: Which specific line?

Comment: Just ran a test and it is at the line:
    if /i "%TIMECHANGE%" == "y" (

Comment: I suspect that the problem may be that this code is itself enclosed as part of a code-block, where the `)` used as part of the `set` statements will close a parenthesis level. Try replacing `)` in the `set`s with `^)`

Comment: Yep that seem to have fixed the issue. Much appreciate your help on that. Couple of questions on this solution. Would it be the same to encase the entire prompt in quotes? Also should I be escaping the ( as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is caused by the `SET /P` lines with the `(...):` text. Use quotation marks as follows and it will work `SET /P "VAR=TEXT:"`:

```
SET /P "TIMECHANGE=Would you like to change the time (y:Yes):"

SET /P "POSTIME=Please enter new time (HH:MM:SS):"

SET /P "DATECHANGE=Would you like to change the date (y:Yes):"

SET /P "POSDATE=Please enter new date (MM-DD-YYYY):"
```

Answer (score 1):

See `delayedexpansion` entries in SO (there are many) for the explanation of why `set`ting a variable and using the new value within a code-block (parenthesised sequence of lines) doesn't appear to change the value.

The easy solution here however is to move the `time` and `date`-setting lines outside of the `if` statements, eg

```
set "postime=%time%"
if /i "%TIMECHANGE%" == "y" (
    SET /P POSTIME=Please enter new time (HH:MM:SS):
)
time "%POSTIME%"
```

Comment: This happens directly at the if statement. I am not even able to get to the line that sets %POSTIME%